# How to align a item to the bottom in columns with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I cannot align an image to the bottom of the page. Even though, the column is the same height it just doesn't align all the way to the bottom.

[image: Align item]

Codepen: https://codepen.io/monsmado/pen/WNvmdOL

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/557x347" class="img-fluid">
        <h2>Lorum Ipsum</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
            <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-end">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x36">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/557x347" class="img-fluid">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-end">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x36">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/557x347" class="img-fluid">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <div class="d-sm-flex align-self-end">
            <a href="#">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/31x36"">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` and `flex-direction: column` to the `.col-sm` and `margin-top: auto` to the div contain your bottom item:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc/pen/WNvmdYB)

If you are using bootstrap 4, you can use class `d-flex flex-column` for `.col-sm` div and `mt-auto` for the bottom item div:

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/cuong97cc/pen/wvaOpER)

Comment: Awesome and thanks man! Used your second example. My logic was to add `align-self-end` to the div containing the content.